# Implement UISearchController using objective-C in existing tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have an existing objective-C based code where there is a view controller having various UItextFileds (sort of a registration form). From 1 of these fields, a new viewcontroller is loaded having UITableView. This viewcontroller also had search box to show search results, which is currently implemented using "searchDisplayController".

I want to change the implementation using "UISearchController", I have to use this existing TableView ( created programmatically already) and implement the UISearchcontoller on top it. Kindly suggest with some good examples/codes to do so.

I am getting many examples in blogs but all are wither using swift or creating their own TableViewContoller.

Answer (score 2):

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
// To have the search bar appear at the top of the tableView
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```